# Can I force my router to transmit using all three of its antennas?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, antenna

I am using [this tool](https://dhalperi.github.io/linux-80211n-csitool/) to study channel state information in a Wi-Fi connection. I have a TP-Link AC1750 router with three antennas, and I installed an Intel 5300 NIC (with three antennas connected) into a PCIe port in a Dell OptiPlex 3020 Small Form Factor. I thought the Wi-Fi connection between the router and NIC would be 3x3 MIMO, but when I inspect the data file the tool generates, it says that there are *two* transmitting antennas and three receiving antennas.

I am not sure why the router is only using two of its three antennas to transmit, but for the purposes of my research, I want to force the router to transmit with full 3x3 MIMO. Is this possible? How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Your router does not support 3x3 MIMO, and your network card only supports the draft revision of the standard 802.11n which does not support MIMO.  You need newer hardware to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Ramhound The data file generated shows that there are two Tx antennas and three Rx antennas. Doesn't that mean that the network card supports MIMO (2x3, in this case)?

Comment: It makes sense you only have two Tx antennas since the router is a dual-band (2.4 GHz and 5.0 GHz).